# BeautifulSoup joins words in different paragraphs

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, epub

I have an EPUB file that I need to use. I'm trying to extract the text from HTML files present in the file. When I run `soup.get_text()` on my extracted HTML content, all paragraphs are joined, combining words together.

I've tried replacing all `<br>` and `</br>` tags with empty spaces. I also tried changing the parser from `html.parser` to `html5lib`.

```py
with self._epub.open(html_file) as chapter:
    html_content = chapter.read().decode('utf-8')
    html_content = html_content.replace('</br>', ' ')
    html_content = html_content.replace('<br>', ' ')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_content, features="html5lib")
    clean_content = soup.get_text()
```

**Input HTML:**

`<p>`Paragraph1. Line 1`</p>`

`<p>`Line 2`<p>`

**Expected output:**

Paragraph1. *Line 1 Line 2*

**Actual ouput:**
Paragraph1. *Line1Line2*

Comment: you miss one thing, p = soup.find_all("p"), then iterate that list. pls post complete html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that.Once you get the html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<p>Paragraph1. Line 1</p><p>Line 2<p>'''

    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    itemtext=''
    for item in soup.select('p'):
        itemtext+=item.text + ' '

    print(itemtext.strip())
```

Output:

```
Paragraph1. Line 1 Line 2
```